# Postgres: GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY reusing deleted record's identity value

Tags: postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS segment
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1),
  )
```

In a single transaction (in Spring JPA), I am deleting and inserting a new record. For new record though, it's using deleted records id value. How can I force postgres to always increment id value and not use deleted record's id value?

Here's my JPA entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "segment", schema = "travel")
public class SegmentTblEntity {

  @Id
  @Basic
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
  private Integer id;
}
```

Comment: You can't provide a value for a column defined as `generated always as identity` unless you specify `overriding system values` which I doubt JPA would use. I don't really know JPA, but I would suspect the obfuscation layer is trying to be smart and doesn't really send an DELETE and INSERT. Maybe it turns it into an UPDATE

Comment: Indeed it was firing an update. Sort-of a bug on my end. Thanks for mentioning it!